# How to Track or Observe that an order is being edited in Magento at backend

Tags: sales-order, edit-order, magento-1.9.2.1

I want to track that I am editing an order at backend in magento, so I want to track that Edit button has been clicked at backend in order section. See below image for more help-

[image]

How can I track an order is being edited at backend.  I also Googled for an observer for this event but could not found. Please anybody can help me here.
Anyone can ask question if he has.

**EDITED:-**
Now I have added following code in config.xml file-

```
<controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_edit_index>
                <observers>
                    <kartparadigm_storecredit>
                        <class>kartparadigm_storecredit/observer</class>
                        <method>editOrder</method>
                    </kartparadigm_storecredit>
                </observers>
</controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_edit_index>
```

and in my **observer.php** file-

```
public function editOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    Mage::log("I am bad boy");
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    Mage::log('order-id- '.$order->getIncrementId());
    Mage::log('order-status- '.$order->getStatus());

}
```

Only "I am a bad boy" is printed in log file and it shows 500 Server Error on edit page. I think its because of second line in observer method but not sure why?

Answer (score 1):

From event `controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_edit_index` you can not get the order object itself (nothing is loaded yet because it is triggered **before** the action.

But at this event you can get the order id, by

```
$orderId=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
```

Then load it:

`$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);`

To get the currently loggedin admin user, try this code

```
$admin = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()
```

source https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/4758/4564

Answer (score 0):

You can add an observer at the predispatch action for this specific controller with the node `controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_edit_index`
Example :
`<controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_edit_index>
    <observers>
        <your_unique_observer_key_here>
            <class>module/observer</class>
            <method>yourFunctionHere</method>
        </your_unique_observer_key_here>
    </observers>
</controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_edit_index>`